# Sending email from Ionic without using composer

Tags: email, ionic-framework

Is there a way to send an email using the Ionic framework without opening a composer app?

I have all the required fields, I just need to send the email.

I've seen that there are plugins (like this http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/emailComposer/) but they all open another screen.

Comment: Are you against a PHP solution? I do the same thing in my app and use PHP to send the mail. Super easy and just a quick $http service call maybe 15 lines of code. You need a mail server though, or you can use googles

Comment: I can't use any server, it has to be on the device, otherwise I would've used one of the email services avaible. That's a constraint I can't do anything about.

Comment: Then there is no way I can think of. If you need to send an email and you don't want to open the devices native mailing system, and you can't utilize a call to any server in your app either, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Most people use a back-end solution if they don't want to use composer.

Comment: I see, well, that might be a problem then :D